# wordpress не отображаются превью картинок в медиа файлах (в админке)

Tags: wordpress

Перенес сайт с локального компа на хостинг. Адреса все поменял. Все работает, но когда я на хостинге пытаюсь загрузить картинку он пишет ошибка HTTP:

[image]

Когда я обновляю админку, появляется файл, но не отображается превью

[image]

Если я нажму на нее, то по прежнему она не отображается

[image]

Ну а так картинка работает и отображается на сайте

[image]

Что сделать, чтобы он нормально загружал и отображал превью картинок? Если я с хостинга переношу базу на свой локальный комп и добавляю, картинки превью корректно отображaются.

Подскажите в чем дело.

Comment: Проверьте права доступов на папку uploads и подпапки

Comment: Проверил 775 стоит

Comment: Включи wp_debug, посмотри логи, на что он конкретно ругается, от версии, тем более 5.4, когда в требованиях стоит 5.2.4, не должно зависеть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался в чем дело, на хостинге версия php 5.4 стояла, поставил версию php 5.5 заработало.